# Count Positive Consecutive Elements in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Question**
Is there a way to count elements along an axis in a dataframe that conform to a condition?

**Background**
I am trying count the consecutive positive digits left to right along the horizontal axis (axis=1).  For example, row zero would result in 0 because the row starts with a negative number, while row one would result in 2 as there are two consecutive positive numbers. Row two would result in 3 and so on.

I've tried looping over it and applying methods, but I am at a loss.

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5))

df

            0           1          2           3           4
0   -1.017333   -0.322464   0.635497    0.248172    1.567705
1   0.038626    0.335656    -1.374040   0.273872    1.613521
2   1.655696    1.456255    0.051992    1.559657    -0.256284
3   -0.776232   -0.386942   0.810013    -0.054174   0.696907
4   -0.250789   -0.135062   1.285705    -0.326607   -1.363189

binary = np.where(df < 0, 0, 1)
binary
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: not clear what you mean by consecutive positive numbers. for instance while you say row 0 has no consecutive integers in row 0 i see 3 column 2, 3, 4. EDIT if Divakar is right then his solution would work.

Comment: The expected o/p would be `[0, 2, 4, 0, 0]`, right?

Comment: That is correct, thank you all.

Comment: Also, if all 5 elements in a row are > 0, we would have the output as `5`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar approach in Pandas

```
In [792]: df_p = df > 0

In [793]: df_p
Out[793]:
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False   True   True   True
1   True   True  False   True   True
2   True   True   True   True  False
3  False  False   True  False   True
4  False  False   True  False  False

In [794]: df_p['0'] * (df_p < df_p.shift(1, axis=1)).idxmax(axis=1).astype(int)
Out[794]:
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    0
4    0
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach -

```
def count_pos_consec_elems(a):
    count = (a[:,1:] < a[:,:-1]).argmax(1)+1
    count[a[:,0] < 1] = 0
    count[a.all(1)] = a.shape[1]
    return count
```

Sample run -

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.602198 -0.899124 -1.104486 -0.106802 -0.092505
1  0.012199 -1.415231  0.604574 -0.133460 -0.264506
2 -0.878637  1.607330 -0.950801 -0.594610 -0.718909
3  1.200000  1.200000  1.200000  1.200000  1.200000
4  1.434637  0.500000  0.421560 -1.001847 -0.980985

In [146]: binary = df.values > 0

In [147]: count_pos_consec_elems(binary)
Out[147]: array([1, 1, 0, 5, 3])
```